# YAML LITERAL style JSON string validity

Tags: yaml

Is below a **valid YAML** as per YAML specification?

```
--- |-
  {
    "response" : ""
  }
```

Note: different implementations of YAML parser treat its validity differently.
So I need to know the ultimate answer as per spec.

Comment: If it helps, here's the reference parser's interpretation: http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/data/1273/index.html

Comment: that's really helpful, thanks @AKX !

Comment: This is valid YAML, which completely independent of that the scalar contains (which happens to be valid in this case as well) JSON. Given your `|-` (and not something like `|-2`), as long as none of the following lines are indented less than the first line, that is valid YAML.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. It's a single scalar containing the JSON string. There should be no ambiguity whatsoever.

The first line contains a [directives end marker](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#c-directives-end) (`---`), followed by a [block scalar header](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#c-b-block-header(m,t)) (`|-`) and three lines of [literal content](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#l-literal-content(n,t)).

Since every following line is indented more than the first one, they are all part of the block scalar (and even would be with zero indentation since the block scalar is the root node of the document).

Parsers that get it properly:

- [Reference Parser](http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/data/1273/index.html) (as mentioned by AKX)
- [PyYAML](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=---+%7C-%0A++%7B%0A++++%22response%22+%3A+%22%22%0A++%7D&type=json)
- [NimYAML](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html) (full disclosure: my work)

(For other implementations, I know of no online parsers to check it quickly.)

Comment: Although I agree on a root block style scalar should work with zero indentation, IIRC this is not an example in the YAML 1.1 spec, but there are examples in the 1.0 and 1.2 specs that show this. PyYAML unfortunately doesn't parse if you don't indent a root level block style scalar (maybe not so useful in a single document file, but I use that extensively in multi-document YAML files).

Comment: @Anthon Yes, having no indentation might lead to failure of some parsers because they don't implement it properly, I wouldn't recommend it. However, it *is* required in both YAML 1.1 and YAML 1.2 – they set the identation level of root's parent to `-1` which means that an indentation of 0 is enough for productions to see the line as part of the block scalar. As the question specifically asked for the spec, I answered according to the spec.

Comment: thanks to all for the answers! Disclosure: this will help to fix couple of bugs in YAML OSS implementations; bug reports will follow shortly to respective teams. Somehow this case seems to have been overlooked.

Comment: @AntonPryamostanov That makes me curious what implementations you are referring to (and whether my `ruamel.yaml`  is included in that list)

Comment: @Anthon let me ask authors if I can disclose the names. I will update within next days. `ruamel.yaml` is not in the list, list has some Java implementations.